# Centralizar um textview

Tags: android

Tenho este *layout* no meu aplicativo:

[image: layout]

E estou criando ele assim:

```
TextView txtCategoria = (TextView)LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.text, null);               
txtCategoria.setText(listenerCategoria.nome);
final ImageButton btCategoria = (ImageButton) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.button, null);
btCategoria.setId((int) listenerCategoria.id);
btCategoria.setImageResource(getResources().getIdentifier(listenerCategoria.nome_foto, "drawable", getPackageName()));
```

Estão separados em 3 `LinearLayout` onde eu adiciono assim:

```
if(l==1){
     layout1.addView(btCategoria);
     layout1.addView(txtCategoria);
     Log.e("l1","entrou "+txtCategoria.getText());
     l=2;
 }else if(l==2){
     layout2.addView(btCategoria);
     layout2.addView(txtCategoria);
     Log.e("l2","entrou "+txtCategoria.getText());
     l=3;
 }else if(l==3){
     layout3.addView(btCategoria);
     layout3.addView(txtCategoria);
     Log.e("l3","entrou "+txtCategoria.getText());
     l=1;
  }
```

O que estou querendo é: É possível centralizar o texto debaixo da foto?

A configuração do `text.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="Medium Text"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/txtCategoria"/>
```

Comment: Mostre o que você tem em `text.xml`.

Comment: coloquei la .... .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você precisa alterar a propriedade `layout_width` para ocupar todo o conteúdo do pai e adicionar `gravity` para centralizar o texto.

Ficando assim:

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/txtCategoria" />
```

Comment: ata , muito obrigado vou tentar